# htaccess rewrite URL complex issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
http://my-domain.com/ppc-landing-page.php?Campaign=Boynton-Beach&AdGroup=Security%20System&Keyword=The%20Best%20Home%20Security%20System%20Company
```

I want this to be rewritten as

```
http://my-domain.com/Boynton-Beach/Boynton-Beach.php?Campaign=Boynton-Beach&AdGroup=Security%20System&Keyword=The%20Best%20Home%20Security%20System%20Company
```

and display the content inside ppc-landing-page.php

The idea is to get the value of Campaign query parameter and rewrite the url in the browser to

```
http://my-domain.com/{$_GET['Campaign']}/{$_GET['Campaign']}.php?Campaign=Boynton-Beach&AdGroup=Security%20System&Keyword=The%20Best%20Home%20Security%20System%20Company
```

the full query string should be there

and then it should replace the $_GET values in the ppc-landing-page.php with the values in the query string and display the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following `RewriteRule` in the .htaccess of your site's document root

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} campaign=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ppc-landing-page.php %1/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Great it worked...But then I need to show the content of ppc-landing-page.php instead %1/%1.php. How am I going to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean? What's the address you expect in the browser?

Comment: I want the address to be %1%1.php but content to be from ppc-landing-page.php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ppc-landing-page.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} campaign=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ppc-landing-page.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ppc-landing-page.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} campaign=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ppc-landing-page.php %1/%1.php [R=302,L]
```

Now I have put something like this...First it worked now it's not ???

Comment: @arco444 I put my htaccess here..Please tell me will this do the trick ?